# How can I optimize Symbolic Link Deletion in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io, symlink, perl-module, directory-traversal

I am working on a Perl script to delete symbolic links in a directory, and I've noticed that the current approach using the find command is taking a considerable amount of time. I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Here is the current code snippet:

```
system("find '$dir' -type l -exec rm -f {} \\;");
```

I've also tried an alternative using unlink and glob:

```
unlink glob("$dir/*") if -e $dir;
```

However, both approaches seem to have their drawbacks, and I'm wondering if there's a more optimized way to achieve symbolic link deletion in Perl.

1. Are there any specific optimizations I can apply to the find command?
2. Is there a more efficient Perl-only solution for deleting symbolic links in a directory?
3. Are there any Perl modules that specialize in directory traversal and link manipulation that could improve performance?

Any insights or suggestions on optimizing the deletion process would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Additional Information:**

- The directory ($dir) typically contains a large number of symbolic links.
- I'm open to using Perl modules or alternative approaches that may offer better performance.
- Performance benchmarks or examples would be especially helpful.

Comment: `find ... -type l -print0 | xargs rm -0f` might be faster since it will not spawn a new instance of `rm` for each file but instead use a single instance of `rm` to delete many files at once. You could also use [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) instead of shell `find` together with perl functions `-l` and `unlink` to not spawn any external processes at all.

Comment: `unlink ... if -e $dir` definitely has its drawbacks. Did you mean `if -l $dir`?

Answer (score 5):

No need to drag external processes like `find` and `rm` into it. The task can be done purely in perl using [`File::Find`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) to traverse the directory tree:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

my $dir = ...; # Fill in the blanks

find(sub { unlink $_ if -l $_ }, $dir);
```

Comment: Re "*The task can be done purely in perl*", Sure, but the question was about doing it faster.

Comment: @Shawn is this the fastest way ?

Comment: @tourist in the time you've spent worrying about that any of the options presented that handle directory trees would be done running a long time ago.

Comment: @Shawn The issue is likely related to Linux caching. The same command appears to have a noticeable delay on the first run, but subsequent executions are faster.

Answer (score 4):

Use `+` instead of `;`, to pass to `rm -f` as many arguments as possible, instead of executing it once per each file:

```
system("find '$dir' -type l -exec rm -f {} \\+");
```

Use `-maxdepth M -mindepth N` if you know how deep in the tree you need to go, for example this searches only the top level:

```
system("find '$dir' -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type l -exec rm -f {} \\+");
```

Comment: Note that `+` is a GNU extension

Comment: `+` is posix these days. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html

Comment: Using `-delete` instead of `-exec rm ...`, now... That's still not standard but much more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

To clean up a single directory, so not recursively, all it takes is something like

```
-l && unlink for glob "$dir/*";
```

This is going to be so fast that the performance is kinda hard to measure.  Just how many files are you deleting, and how often?

One clear drawback of the above [postfix](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers) use of the `for` loop is that one cannot check errors normally.  This is important, specially when deleting a lot of files, so better write it out

```
for my $file (glob "$dir/*") {
    if (-l $file) { 
        unlink $file or warn "Error unlinking $file: $!"
    }
}
```

Doing it this way does "affect" performance but in a most minuscule way.

---

I'm wondering ... how many *entries* altogether (files, dirs, links, etc) are in that directory?  If there is an excessive number, like hundreds of thousands, then that by itself may slow down the traversal to a crawl.  Scanning larger directories of course takes more time but if the number of entries gets extreme the system may get knocked down on its knees, so to speak; a basic listing from a shell can take 10-20 minutes.

Looking into this at one point I found that if the number is really excessive the system (`ls`, `find` etc) suffers far more than a program.  If that observation holds true generally, or at least on your system as well, then doing it in Perl would again be better.

And if this is really the concern -- excessive number of files -- then two options come to mind.

[File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Glob) library provides means via its [bsd_glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Glob#bsd_glob) to not sort the filelist

```
use File::Glob qw(:bsd_glob);

for my $file ( bsd_glob("$dir/*", GLOB_NOSORT) ) { 
    ...
}
```

This should help some if there is indeed a lot of files.  Thanks to Shawn for a comment.

The other possibility is to avoid building the full filelist at once, what is done by using `glob` in a list context, like in a `for` loop. In scalar context `glob` iterates, taking one filename at a time and this is worth trying if you really have quarter million files or some such

```
while ( my $file = glob "$dir/*" ) { 
    if (-l $file) { 
        unlink $file or warn "Error unlinking $file: $!"
    }
}
```

Try and time all these, and clarify how slow this is and how many files -- and links -- you have.

Comment: Using [`bsd_glob()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Glob#bsd_glob) with the `GLOB_NOSORT` option might be useful with this approach.

Comment: @Shawn Indeed, a good reminder.  Added, thank you

Comment: @zdim the directory contains around 50K files ( including sub directories ), and I need to search recursively all directories to get the symlinks.

Comment: @tourist "_and I need to search recursively_"  -- ah, then this isn't it.  I didn't know you need it recursively since the question attempts with `glob`, which decidedly doesn't do recursion.

Comment: @zdim @Shawn I am trying out `find(sub { unlink $_ or warn "WARNING: Failed to unlink $_: $!\n" if -l $_ }, $dir);` , but just wondering if it's most efficient. any inputs ?